# Is it necessary for a family member of an EU citizen to write travel dates in the visa application for Ireland?

Tags: visas, eu, ireland, citizen

I am applying as a family member of an EU citizen for Ireland. I want to clarify, is it compulsory to write the intended dates of travel on the visa application?

Answer (score 5):

Yes. For a short term visa you need to enter both your proposed dates, for a long term visa you need only enter the proposed arrival, and can leave departure date blank.

I got this information from the actual visa application, and have attached a screenshot below so you can see the data yourself, note how a red * sign indicates a field that must be entered.

[image: Image of the visa application page]

Comment: What should the family member do if their intention is to remain indefinitely?  Such people are supposed to apply for short-stay visas.